# Funky behaviour of derivative

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, interpolation, calculus-and-analysis

I'm solving a set of differential equations for the variables H(t), x(t) and a(t). Then I construct a function z(t) from these, and another function w(t) from z(t). w(t) contains terms such as the third time derivative of x(t) (x'''(t)), and it has some funny behaviour (see plot): even though z'(t) seems smooth, z''(t) and consequently w(t) has some jumps.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Code:

```
(*Parameters*)
ti = 1;
xp = 10;
mp = (8*Pi)^(-1/2);
mu = 10^(-5)*mp;

(*Background potential*)

V[x_, n_] := mu^2*x^n;

(*Dynamical eqs*)

eq1[x_, H_, t_, n_] := H^2 - 1/(3 mp^2)*(1/2 D[x, t]^2 + V[x, n])
eq2[x_, H_, t_, n_] := D[x, {t, 2}] + 3 D[x, t]*H + D[V[x, n], x]

(*Solve the dynamical equations*)
solution =  
  NDSolve[ {eq1[x[t], H[t], t, 2] == 0, eq2[x[t], H[t], t, 2] == 0, 
    xp - Sqrt[2/3]*mp*Log[ti] == x[ti], -Sqrt[2/3]*mp/ti == x'[ti], 
    1/(3*ti) == H[ti], H'[ti] == 1/3, a'[t]/a[t] == H[t]}, {H, x, 
    a}, {t, 0.1, 10^8}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

z[t_] = a[t]*x'[t]/H[t] /. solution;

w[t_] = (D[z[t], {t, 2}]* (a[t]^2 /. solution) + 
   z'[t]*(a'[t] /. solution)*(a[t] /. solution))/z[t];

Plot[{z[t], z'[t], z''[t], w[t]}, {t, 1, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Plot produced:

[image]

Comment: I think I know how to fix it, but your code is incomplete/giving errors.  Hard to check whether I'm right....

Comment: What errors are you getting? I can reproduce the plot above with only a warning message (warning that it's a system of DAEs), by just pasting the code in an empty notebook.

Comment: Michael E2 will not receive a copy of your response, unless you include @MichaelE2 in it.  I too encounter warnings: "NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations." and "NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions."  The first of these occurs, because no derivatives of `H` appear in the two ODEs.

Comment: OK, I tried a different version and I got something that looks like your plot with only a `NDSolve::pdord` warning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on notifications. I understand why the first message occurs, but this is just how the equations are. Do you still get this error if you omit the AccuracyGoal? I still don't get this error - I'm using Mathematica 10.3.

Comment: Include the option `InterpolationOrder -> 5` in `DSolve`.  Otherwise, you loose too much precision when taking derivatives.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Evidently, `NDSolve` has chosen `a[ti] == 1` as the boundary conditions for `a[t]`, but I do not see how this follows from the specified boundary conditions.  Did `NDSolve` pull this out of the air?

Comment: @fja  I recommend that you specify a initial condition for `a` at `ti`.  Also, the `H'[ti]` condition does not appear to do anything and probably can be deleted.

Comment: Should `H'[ti] == 1/3` be `H'[ti] == -1/3`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It should be! Although this doesn't seem to change the results. In the end I swapped variables, coordinate time to conformal time, and I'm not using this initial condition.  Thank you for your great in-depth answers, though! I learnt a lot from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be of interest to present a solution requiring minimal changes to the code in the question, namely adding `a[ti] == 1` (so that the code runs on Ver 11.0.1; `DSolve` chooses `a[ti] == 1` by default in earlier versions) and `InterpolationOrder -> 5` (to eliminate the spiky behavior of some of the curves in the question, as I noted in an early comment).  With these changes only, the curves are the same as in the solution by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), apart from a small spike in `w` at about `t == 3.4` (which can be eliminated with the `Plot` option `PlotPoints -> 20`.  Curves of the three functions obtained directly from `NDSolve` are,

```
LogLogPlot[(H /. Flatten@solution)[t], {t, 1, 10^8}]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[(a /. Flatten@solution)[t], {t, 1, 10^8}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[(x /. Flatten@solution)[t], {t, 1, 10^8}, PlotRange -> {-.05, .05}]
```

[image]

The small `PlotRange` is used to make visible the late-time oscillations.

Comment: I notice you're not plotting `z''[t]` and `w[t]`, which are the functions OP desired to be smooth. Are they smooth, or do they have jumps [like these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7VrZ6.png), which I get in V10.4.1, V11.0.0, and others?  The question in my mind is which solution is correct, the one with a singularity around `t = 33000` (with the differentiated 1st ODE) or the one that doesn't. My solution has a persistent singularity, no matter what method (RK, LDSODA, Extrapolation) or working precision.

Comment: @MichaelE2  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQGcr.png) is an image of my notebook.  I reproduced the choppy behavior you observed at very small `t` but eliminated it with `MaxStepFraction -> 10^-3,`  I do not observe the choppy behavior you observed near `t == 600000`.  In general, I do not have much difficulty with `DSolve` but I sometimes have difficulty with `Plot` (see Out[47]), perhaps because the solutions become exponentially large at late `t`.

Comment: I get discontinuities at different locations with your method than with mine, about 70 of them, which stands to reason, since the discontinuities arise from the interpolation method ``NDSolve`CubicHermite``, which happens at 4444 of the 23713 steps in `solution1` of your notebook. ([See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r1LsZ.png).) Maybe it's not worth worrying about, since the OP seems satisfied.

Comment: @MichaelE2  What is your algorithm for identifying the 70 or so discontinuities?  Thanks.

Comment: It was something like ``chpos = Position[if, NDSolve`CubicHermite][[All, -1]]; discont = Flatten[if["Grid"][[chpos]]]; Mean /@ Split[discont, (#2 - #1)/#2 < 0.1 &]``. (I had an FE crash & I hadn't saved this code. The `Split` criterion has to be tweaked to suit this particular problem.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks.  I ran this code and found 59 location, but the few I plotted did not seem abnormal.  Did you have a specific problematic case?

Comment: With `a[ti]==1` and `InterpolationOrder -> 5` added to OP's code, ``if = x /. First@solution; chpos = Position[if, NDSolve`CubicHermite][[All, -1]]; discont0 = Flatten[if["Grid"][[chpos]]]; discont = Mean /@ Split[discont0, (#2 - #1)/#2 < 0.1 &]; lin[{t_, a_, b_}] := ((b - t) w[a] + (t - a) w[b])/(b - a); dom = {t, 0.99 #, 1.01 #} &@discont[[10]]; Plot[{w[t] - lin[dom]}, Evaluate@dom, PlotLabel -> Row[w /@ Rest@dom, ", "]]`` produces this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6o8.png

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the default interpolating functions returned by `NDSolve` are cubic Hermite interpolations. The first derivative will be continuous but (most likely) with singularities at the steps (values of `t` for each step). The second derivative will be pretty much useless.  The fix is to use `InterpolationOrder -> All` (and hope for the best).

With the `InterpolationOrder -> All`, the interpolation with the default LSODA method is primarily by local series, mainly of order 4 or 5. It seems impossible to completely avoid cubic Hermite interpolation with the LSODA method, at least with this ODE.  However, if we use `Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"` and set up the ODE system in a nicer way, we can get an interpolation completely in terms of Chebyshev series order 8 or 9, which are smooth enough for plotting the OP's functions.

One significant change is differentiating the first ODE and explicitly solving for `H'[t]` and `x''[t]` for `NDSolve`.  For some reason `NDSolve[]` had trouble solving for the derivatives.  Also, as @bbgodfrey pointed out in a comment, `a[t]` does not have a initial value; in the OP's code, `NDSolve[]` arbitrarily assign an initial value of `1`.

```
(* use OP's parameters and other definitions *)
ics = {xp - Sqrt[2/3]*mp*Log[ti] == x[ti], -Sqrt[2/3]*mp/ti == x'[ti],
    1/(3*ti) == H[ti],
    (*H'[ti] == 1/3,*)   (* problematic & seems to be wrong -- omit *)
    a[ti] == 1};         (* this could be anything -- OP should specify *)
ode = {Equal @@@ First@Solve[{
       D[H[t]^2 - 8/3 π (x[t]^2/(80000000000 π) + 1/2 x'[t]^2) == 0, t],
       x[t]/(40000000000 π) + 3 H[t] x'[t] + x''[t] == 0},
      {H'[t], x''[t]}],
      a'[t]/a[t] == H[t]};

solution = NDSolve[{ode, ics},
   {H, x, a}, {t, 0.1, 10^2},
   InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta",
   AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

z[t_] = a[t]*x'[t]/H[t] /. solution;
w[t_] = (D[z[t], {t, 2}]*(a[t]^2 /. solution) + 
     z'[t]*(a'[t] /. solution)*(a[t] /. solution))/z[t];
```

Then the plot looks like this:

```
Plot[{z[t], z'[t], z''[t], w[t]}, {t, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: You can check the principal interpolation method with

```
x["InterpolationMethod"] /. solution
(*  {"Chebyshev"}  *)
```

Comment: OK, RK only integrate out to 33000....but I've got to go.  It's a bit ornery, this problem: so many things almost work. :/ -- Or maybe there's a real singularity?

Comment: `NDSolve` with `Method` not specified integrates to 10^8 without difficulty.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm not sure about the "without difficulty," at least from the point of view of the plotted expressions.  I mean, one can have a smooth result out to 33K or [a choppy result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl4Dw.png) out to `10^8`.  Or do you have a different experience?

Comment: With 10.4.1, I have smooth curves to 10^8.  What version are you using for this problem?  I should add that I obtain the same results with 11.0.1, if I provide an initial condition for`[a[ti]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm using V11.0.0.